# Is it okay for me to open the door?

Tags: grammar

> Is it okay for me to open the door?

In this sentence, does 'it' refer to 'for me to open the door'? Is 'it' an anticipatory subject? Or is 'it' an impersonal pronoun, which does not refer to anything?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay for me to open the door?

In this sentence, *it* is a **dummy pronoun** and is simply serving a syntactical role (to make the sentence grammatical) rather than referring to something specific. *It* doesn't stand for (or refer to) anything in particular.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun):

> In the phrase "**it** is raining—", the verb *to rain* is usually considered semantically impersonal, even though it appears as syntactically intransitive; in this view, the required *it* is to be considered a dummy word.

Note that there is some controversy over this specific interpretation. However, what's not in dispute is that *it* is not a referential pronoun. In other words, you can't replace it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

"It" refers to "for me to open the door". To make things more clear, we can split the sentence:

> - I want to **open the door**.
> - Is **it** OK?